# Where is the classpath variable restored in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I manually add another variable like `M2_REPO` pointing to a directory,

I don't find it in either `.project` or `.classpath`,

where is it restored then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored in the JDT settings in your workspace. Check this file under your workspace root,

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

This file is not project specific so classpath var is shared by the whole workspace.

Answer (score -1):

It's stored in your workspace file.

Comment: There is only a `.metadata` directory and no project specific settings.

Comment: A classpath variable isn't project specific. I don't know exactly where it is stored, but if you change your workspace, you have do define the classpath variable again. So it has to be somewhere inside your workspace configs.

Comment: I just looked up all possible files there,but no luck.

Comment: Forced downvote... there is no information provided in this answer, just a general gesture towards where it might be.